# EF/LINQ How to include child entities when there is a bidirectional relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**Environment**

I am using Entity Framework 5 on Framework 4.0. (This means I am actually using EF 4.4).
As entities I use STE (Self Tracking Entities) because I am working in an N-Tier application.
We use a database driven approach because EF was introduced later in the game.

**Context**

I have 2 Entities that both have a navigation property to each other. (EntityA has a navigation property to EntityB, and EntityB one to EntityA).
The relation is 'EntityA > One-TO-Many > EntityB'. When I want to load the child Entities via a LINQ expression, I need to use INCLUDE (STE => Eager Loading) because I will pass all data trough several tiers.

**The code**

Here is my code to call EntityA with its EntityB children.

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
     var result = (from s in ctx.EntityA.Include("EntityB")
                   where s.Id = 11111
                   orderby s.TimeUpdated descending 
                   select s)
               .Take(10)
               .ToList();
     return result;
}
```

**The error**

> System.StackOverflowException {Cannot evaluate expression because the
>   current thread is in a stack overflow state.}

There is no error when I remove the 'INCLUDE'.
I guess the reason is straightforward. I Want to load EntityA with child records EntityB, EntityB records wants to load its parent EntityA everytime, and EntityA ... I guess everyone understands the infinite loop here.

**My solutions or alternatives**

- I go to my EDMX file and remove the navigation property for EntityA in EntityB. If I now want to load data about EntityA while I have an EntityB to my disposal. I need to do a separate DB request and I have 2 different objects that I have to pass on trough my tiers.
- Avoid using include, load separately the EntityA and push it into the Navigation property of my EntityB that refers to my EntityA.

**the question**

Are there better alternatives or approaches to fix this in my situation ? Should I go on with one of my alternatives I proposed or not? Because I was hoping for a better and cleaner solution.

I Thank you for your time

Ian

Comment: +1 For a very good (1st) question for you.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem in EF 5 (Visual Studio 2012) and I don't get any errors. Is there anything else that could cause your problem? Is it working with a simple POCO setup? (Sidenote.. I have worked with STE before and now I'm realy trying to avoid them. Are you sure you want to use STE?)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error either (EF5, .NET 4.0).  Is it possible to post the stacktrace and maybe blank the sensitive data?

Comment: Ok I discovered next: My project is an Webapp. When I run the Webapp locally on the PC and the method is invoked this error is thrown.
When I run exactly the same method from a Test class no errors are thrown. But when the webapp throws the error I can fix it by removing the 'include' so I assume the error has to be in this line.
More stacktrace I dont have except for 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'.

Comment: @WouterdeKort : Because I am stuck with the N-tier design, I cannot use other types

Comment: You can use plain DTO's. Keep your domain model on the server and only send simple dtos trough WCF

Comment: To break before the stackoverflow you can set a breakpoint on your query with a condition like 'new StackTrace().FrameCount > 400', Then you can examine the Call Stack.  I also fully agree with Wouter, STE is a pain in the ass (learned this the hard way), effectively you can map the entities to dto’s and then map back to entities and use ApplyCurrentValues to let the context generate the changes on a Save.

Comment: @WouterdeKort, I discovered the error was not raised on the query itself but two layers up. I was throwing the results to the code-behind of my page and the moment it was supposed to send the results over a AjaxPro method, the StackOverFlow invoked. So I converted my result objects to DTOs like you suggested and it killed the problems. Thank you ! Feel free to reply as answer so I can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem in EF 5 (Visual Studio 2012) and I don't get any errors. Is there anything else that could cause your problem? Is it working with a simple POCO setup?

I also wanted to note that STE's can give you quite a headache. I have worked with STE before and now I'm really trying to avoid them. Are you sure you want to use STE?

Instead of using STE's you can use plain old DTO's. You will keep your rich domain model on the server and only send the data that is necessary to the client. This way you can create tailored DTO's with the least amount of data for each use case.

Answer (score 0):

I came here to say to you "You can use `Include`" but obviously it does not help you in this situation.

As I read on the internet usually, there is some workarounds when we suspect (or have) an infinite loop case:

1. We can use [Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896249.aspx) operations by using `foreach` and load the children manually.
2. We can create a database [view that is a recursive query](http://web.archive.org/web/20090331190541/http://www.webinade.com/web-development/creating-recursive-sql-calls-for-tables-with-parent-child-relationships) by itself (and use its entity).

Comment: - 1. Load operations can't be applied because my navigation properties are no _EntityCollections<EntityA>_ but _TrackableCollection<EntityA>_

 - 2. Saddly this does not apply for my context. For example, I want to easily access the Parent Entity (EntityA) and save it as a field of my EntityB.

I tested 'context.LoadProperty(EntityB, "EntityA")' But generates also to same StackOverflowException.

Thank you for the tips

Answer (score -1):

[see this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783004)

however I have update 4 installed and still can't debug